# Immutable.js allows mutating of objects

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Here is an example Redux reducer:

```
case REDUCE_ME:
  const newState = state.setIn(['a', 'b', 'c'], payload);
  payload.id = 'I MANIPULATE STORE!'; 
  return newState; // newState.a.b.c.id is 'I MANIPULATE STORE!'
```

Expected behavior:  `id` should not be changed.

Thanks to the helpers.

Comment: What do you mean on the ''should not be possible' comment? payload is just a common variable, it does not become immutable just because you use it to initialize something immutable.

Comment: @tevemadar the comment was confusing. I meant that it should not influence newState.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the point is because your payload is not immutable object. Same thing with less context:

```
const a = {'foo': 'bar};
```

You can't re-assign value to a like `a = 'baz';` because `a` is a constant. But you can change value of `a.foo` because it's not constant/immutable. You can use `a.foo = 'baz';` and it will work. So you are doing the same thing with immutableJs. If you want to have full immutable structure, convert your payload to immutable too. And you have updated value because immutablejs holds a pointer to source variable without creating new local instance of that value.

In short - use `payload = Immutable.fromJS(payload)` before using payload and you will be fine with all structure as immutable.

```
const state1 = new Immutable.fromJS({
   a: {
       b: {
           c: 'foo'
       }
   }
});

console.log('State 1', state1.toJS());

let payload = 'bar';
const state2 = state1.setIn(['a','b','c'], payload);
console.log('state2 after 1st change',state2.toJS());

payload = 'baz';

console.log('state2 adter 2nd change',state2.toJS()); // c will be still bar

let payload2 = {'a': 'bar'};
// attaching payload2 which can not be changed from object to something else but it's inside values can be changed.
// same like with const a = {'foo': 'bar}; you cant re-assign value to a, but you can modify a.foo = 'whatever else';
const state3 = state1.setIn(['a','b','c'], payload2);  
console.log('state3 after 1st change',state3.toJS());

payload2.a = 'baz';
console.log('state3 after 2nd change (switched to baz)',state3.toJS());

payload2 = 'baz';
console.log('state3 after 3rd change (tried to set payload2 to string)',state3.toJS());
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYNWNr

Comment: that's not quite like the code in the question ... payload is obviously an object with an id property, which the OP is changing

Comment: Thanks @LukasLiesis , this makes sense. I must add, that when doing the same with ``` state.merge(payload)`` and then trying to change `payload` this **doesnt** change the store.